# C++, Typedef a Static getInstance function

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I Have this singleton "TextureHandler" Class which works fine using this **"TextureHandler::getInstance()->functionName()"**, But... what i want to do is making a typedef **"TxHandler"** for the **getInstance()** function, so i can use it like this **"TxHandler->functionName()"**, But I'm getting this error: **expected initializer before 'TxHandler'.**

```
#ifndef TEXTUREHANDLER_H
#define TEXTUREHANDLER_H

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "Defs.h"

// Engine's texture handler class
class TextureHandler
{
    // private constructor for singleton
    TextureHandler() {}
    static TextureHandler* instance;

    // textures string map
    map<string, SDL_Texture*> tMap;

    public:
        // getInstance singleton function
        static inline TextureHandler* getInstance()
        {
            if(instance == NULL)
            {
                // create a pointer to the object
                instance = new TextureHandler();
                return instance;
            }
            return instance;
        }

        bool load(SDL_Renderer* renderer, string id, const char* filename);
        bool loadText(SDL_Renderer* renderer, string id, const char* text, TTF_Font* font, SDL_Color color);
        void render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, string id, int x, int y, int w=0, int h=0, int center=0, SDL_Rect* clip=NULL, SDL_RendererFlip flip=SDL_FLIP_NONE);
        void free(string id);
        int getWidth(string id);
        int getHeight(string id);
};

// TextureHandler instance typedef
typedef TextureHandler::getInstance() TxHandler;

#endif
```

Comment: `typedef` is for types. `TextureHandler::getInstance()` isn't one.

Comment: Did you mean -->  typedef TextureHandler * TxHandler;

Comment: No, I mean a typedef to the instance function, so i can use it as following **TxHandler->functionName()** and not **TxHandler::getInstance()->functionName**

Comment: The point is you can't do that because it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typedef` allows you to create an alias for a *type*. You cannot use it to name an instance of that type.

The closest you can get to the functionality you're after is to store the result of `TextureHandler::getInstance()` in a pointer:

```
TextureHandler* TxHandler = TextureHandler::getInstance();
....
TxHandler->functionName();
```

Comment: That's it, This is what i was looking for, Thanks for explaining when to use typedefs

Answer (score 0):

As juanchopanza said in comment, `typedef` declares an alias for a type. It is not a general macro.

If you do not want to repeatedly type `TextureHandler::getInstance()`, you could use a macro :

```
#define TxHandler TextureHandler::getInstance()
```

But it is just syntactic sugar, and the compiler will generate exactly same code.

Comment: Thanks, Both Answers are working, now i know when to use tyedefs ;)